# Lack of security for force.com sites?

Tags: salesforce

I am exposing a page with a standardcontroller="account" to a force.com site facing the public. This page displays account specific data to the clients. Now when a customer logs in to my website I want him to have access to his account's data and only his account data. Here is the problem; the url for a page with a standardcontroller has a Id field, such as "https//www.myforcesite.force.com/AccountViewPage?Id=a82347dod". If a user changes a few keys on the Id, it is very easy for him to access other people's account page and bypass the login process. How can I prevent that.

I opened a ticket with salesforce but they told me its working as intended. I don't think a vulnerability to a trivial brute force attack should be intended so I want to know if there are any fixes?

Comment: Is it really that easy to find another valid ID?

Comment: Are you passing the ID? isn't it associated with the Login? can you check that login Id with the account ID each time?

Comment: @Gumbo. Yes most Id vary by only 1 character (the last one).

Answer (score 3):

Create one StandardController extension and check if the logged user in your website has the permission to view that account.
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/apex_pages_standardcontroller.htm

Comment: Yes, this is the way to do it.  You'll need to somehow implement your own custom authorization mechanism to prevent users from accessing pages they're not allowed to view.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [URL rewriting](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_site_urlRewriter.htm) for force.com site.

> For example, let's say that you have a blog site. Without URL rewriting, a blog entry's URL might look like this: http://myblog.force.com/posts?id=003D000000Q0PcN
>
> With URL rewriting, your users can access blog posts by date and
>   title, say, instead of by record ID. The URL for one of your New
>   Year's Eve posts might be:
>   http://myblog.force.com/posts/2009/12/31/auld-lang-syne